# Essential infimum, positive measure

Tags: real-analysis

I have a fundamental question about measure theory.

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a measure space. We assume $\mu(X)>0$.

Let $f$ be a $\mathcal{B}$-measurable function.

**Question**

I want to show the following

> For $\alpha>0$, there exsits a $\mathcal{B}$-measurable set $B$ such
>   that $\mu(B)>0$ and  \begin{align*} f(x) \leq \mbox{essinf}_{x \in X}
>  f(x) +\alpha\quad \mbox{on}\quad B \end{align*}

**My idea**

Since $\displaystyle \mbox{essinf}_{x \in X}f(x)=\sup\left\{b \in \mathbb{R}: \mu \left(\left\{x \in X:f(x)<b\right\} \right)=0 \right\}$, for $\alpha>0$, there exists $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\mbox{essinf}_{x \in X}f(x)-\alpha <\beta,\quad \mu\left(\left\{x \in X:f(x)<\beta\right\} \right)=0,
\end{align*}
$\mu(\left\{x \in X:f(x) \geq \beta\right\})=\mu(X)-\mu\left(\left\{x \in X:f(x)<\beta\right\} \right)=\mu(X)>0$, 
\begin{align*}
\mbox{essinf}_{x \in X}f(x)-\alpha \leq f(x)\quad \mbox{on}\quad B:= \left\{x \in X:f(x) \geq \beta\right\}
\end{align*}

But I think this argument is wrong. Will you tell me where I am wrong?

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of $\operatorname{essinf}(f)$,

$$f(x) \geq \operatorname{essinf}(f) $$ for almost every $x \in X$. Therefore, if there was $\alpha >0$ such that $f(x) > \operatorname{essinf}(x) + \alpha$ for almost every $x \in X$, we could have chosen this value as the sup to begin with. Ergo, the set $$\{x \in X: f(x) \leq \operatorname{essinf}(f) + \alpha \}$$ must have non-zero measure, and is indeed measurable as a level set of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I understood!